# How to check if a binary tree is complete in Java

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am having a lot of trouble with this task. Using the Wikipedia definition for a complete binary tree:

> A complete binary tree is a binary tree in which every level, except possibly the last, is completely filled, and all nodes are as far left as possible

I need a way of checking for these conditions, but no matter how much I try, I can't seem to come up with anything. If I were to pass a `TreeNode tree` input into a `checkComplete` method how could I go about going through the binary tree and checking that it is complete? Can anyone help with pseudocode or an explanation of how this is possible? There was another question here: [How to determine whether a binary tree is complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442674/how-to-determine-whether-a-binary-tree-is-complete)

This one had an answer with pseudocode in it, but I couldn't understand where all the random variables were coming from or what they were meant to represent or why there were two values in brackets in the last 3 lines. If anyone could help with another representation I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traverse the tree left-to-right. There are several critical points at which you'll want to store or compare information:

- When you hit the first leaf node.
- When you hit subsequent leaf nodes.
- When you hit the first leaf node with a different distance from the root.

Since this is homework, you should probably take it the rest of the way from that hint.

Comment: So I would traverse the tree in preorder and find the first leaf node with `if (tree.left == null && tree.right == null)` and in the condition I would store the current depth to a global variable and then compare that with the next leaf node somehow and if they're equal return true. If they're different I'd store the bigger value at maxValue and store the smaller value at minValue. Then if maxValue and minValue only differ by 1 or 0 by the end of it, is that then a complete binary tree? That's all I could come up with...

Comment: You're on the right track. However, you have to guarantee that the last row is filled left-to-right. So what must happen at the first leaf node after the left-most that has a different depth? What must not happen at leaf nodes subsequent to that step?

Comment: Also, a better approach than a global variable is to carry data along the traversal. For example, you can pass the same object to the visitation of each node, and record observations in that object. Optionally, this object can also contain the *behavior* that should be performed on each node -- this is known as the Visitor pattern.

Comment: Brain is fizzling out due to all-nighter. I'll try this out after I wake up tomorrow and report back. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 2):

```
int CT()
{
  int lh=0, rh=0, sign=1;
  if (!root->left && !root->right) 
    return 1;
  if (!root->left && root->right) 
    return 0;

  lh = CT(root->left);
  rh = CT(root->right);

  if (lh == 0 || rh == 0) 
    return 0;
  if (lh < 0 && rh < 0) 
    return 0;
  if (lh < 0 || rh < 0) 
    sign = -1;
  if (|lh| == |rh| ) 
    return (|lh|+1)*sign;
  elseif (rh == lh-1) 
    return -(|lh|+1);
  else return 0;
}

if CT returns '0' - its not a complete tree.
'-' is used to check mismatch in height is encountered on one subtree only.
```

Comment: Advanced but intresting :-) If he uses this for homework then he will defo fail.  your code has some level of complexity.