# Whether a given Binary Tree is complete or not

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given a Binary Tree, write a function to check whether the given Binary Tree is Complete Binary Tree or not.

A complete binary tree is a binary tree in which every level, except possibly the last, is completely filled, and all nodes are as far left as possible. source: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees)

> My approach is do BFS using queue and count the no of nodes. Run a
> loop till the queue is not null but break once you find one of the
> below condition holds good:
>
> 1. left node is not present for a node
> 2. left node is present but right node is not present.
>
> Now we can compare the count that we get from the above approach and
> the original count of the nodes in the tree. If both equal then
> complete binary tree else not.

Please tell me whether the approach is correct or not. Thanks.

This question is same as that of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442674/how-to-determine-whether-a-binary-tree-is-complete). But i wan to verify my method here.

**Edit:**
The algorithm is verified by @**Boris Strandjev** below. I felt this is the easiest algorithm to implement out of some algorithms available in net. Sincere apologize if you do not agree with my assertion.

Comment: @RahulTripathi thanks for the link. But i want to verify my algo here. Can you please help me in that?

Comment: how/when do you count the nodes?

Comment: You don't even need to count nodes, just see if you got to the end of the tree or terminated early. Counting is O(n) like the algorithm itself, but doesn't really seem necessary.

Comment: Please note that you must count the nodes you push into the queue, and you must check those conditions after pushing node's children into the queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your algorithm should solve the problem.

What you are doing with the BFS is entirely equivalent to drawing the tree and then tracing the nodes with your finger top-down and left-right. The first time you can not continue you stop tracing with your finger. If you have not counted all the nodes then the structure is not as expected obviously.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But my code will return correct result for this. suppose queue is q. Now for your input. q will have 1, then pop 1 and push left child 2 and right child 3. Now  pop 2, 2 will not have left child so break. Now from this we will get the count 3 but originally the tree has 5, hence binary tree is not complete. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @trying: sorry i misunderstood your algorithm I am initiating reitaration over it will feedback in 2-3 mins.

Comment: @Trying edited. I think you are good to go with this approach

Comment: are you saying that my algorithm will work as it is? please conform. Anyways thanks for your effort.

Comment: @Trying I confirm. Your algorithm will work as is. I have explained in my answer why.